# How can I run PuLP simulation for a finite time?

Tags: python, pulp

I am running a facility location problem on python and want to run it for only 10 minutes as it will take more than 2 hours for complete solution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which solver are you using. But generally it's one parameter `maxSeconds` when you create the solver. For example let assume you're using XPRESS, and you want it run 10mins and stop, you can create the solver like

```
solver = XPRESS(maxSeconds=10 * 60)
```